# Operation is not allowed when the object is closed. Updated Visual Basic 2012 to Update 3

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, visual-studio-2012, connection-string

My program was working until yesterday. But my company moved to a new domain and I also had to do that. Now I cannot connect to SQL Server, what should I change in my connection string?

```
Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=Pedram;Data Source=DELL_RACK
```

The error I get for my inserts is:

> Operation is not allowed when the object is closed.

By the way, I think I also upgraded my Visual Studio to Update 3. Could this also be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The connection string will stay the same. It won't change at all. This relies on the user's security context to authenticate to sql server. Therefore, we'll need to fix it so that the users accessing the database are authorized to use the database.

The change will need to be either in how you choose what user is logged in (ie: if this is an asp.net site doing impersonation, or similar process for setting the current user) orby grant login rights to users in the new domain in Sql Server, or both.

Comment: You see I can easily connect to my SQL Server Management studio with no problem. But I cannot get my function to work anymore. I'm developing a console application with c# by the way. I can also run queries on SQL Server.

Comment: I get this error on my inserts: "Operation is not allowed when the object is closed." but when I run the same query on SQL Server it works fine.

Comment: That error is because the connection did not open (it's still closed).  It works for you in Sql Server because your specific account was granted access to the DB.

Comment: But it's the same code that was working until yesterday. Nothing has changed, except that I also upgraded my visual studio 2013 to update three. can that be the problem?

Comment: You said they also changed the Active Directory Domain. That would have a _huge_ impact on integrated security with sql server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL Server authentication Mix mode.

For create a `Connection String` in mix mode use this

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;
Password=myPassword;
```

and en total you can see this link : [http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/][1]

if you use mix mode authentication , change windows permission can not make error in your program.